# Get unique years from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have array with below structure, i want get array of unique year from that array.

I have got required output using for loop but can any suggest better way to get required output.

```
[
    { date = "2015-12-19 11:56:51 +0000"; },
    { date = "2015-12-19 11:56:51 +0000"; },
    { date = "2015-12-19 11:56:52 +0000"; },
    { date = "2013-11-19 11:56:52 +0000"; },
    { date = "2013-09-20 11:56:52 +0000"; },
    { date = "2014-12-07 11:56:58 +0000"; },
    { date = "2015-12-19 11:57:03 +0000"; },
    { date = "2012-08-08 11:57:07 +0000"; },
    { date = "2010-08-19 11:57:20 +0000"; }
]
```

For above array output array should be 
["2015", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2010"]

Here is code which i am using right now:

```
NSMutableSet *setDate = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSDictionary *dicData in arrayDates) {
    NSString *strDate = [[dicData valueForKeyPath:@"date"] substringToIndex:4];
  // my date format always same so no issue with substring
    [setDate addObject:strDate];
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Loop over the array, convert the strings to Date, get the year out of it, put that in a array if it does not already contain the year.

Comment: @luk2302 i have done that one, other than that do we have any solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way or the other you need to loop over array's elements. It could be a "for" loop, a "foreach" loop, or a `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`, but the loop is going to be there.

Since years are relatively small integers, one way of collecting the output is to use `NSIndexSet`. This set is very fast, and it is always sorted. Here is a solution that uses `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`

```
NSMutableIndexSet *res = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
[myDates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id d, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
    NSDateComponents *dc = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:d];
    [res addIndex:[dc year]];
}];
```

Now `res` contains unique years from dates in your `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what dasblinkenlight said in his answer, this can be done without a loop (well, at least without writing the loop explicitly ;-).

You can add a category on `NSDate`, containing a method which returns year:

```
@interface NSDate (Year)

- (NSInteger)my_year;

@end

@implementation NSDate (Year)

- (NSInteger)my_year
{
  NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:self];
  return components.year;
}

@end
```

Then you can use the power of Key-Value Coding:

```
//look, ma! no loops! no set!
 NSArray *uniqueYears = [dates valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.my_year"];
```

Of course writing a category only for this purpose is an overkill. But the method `my_year` can be reused in other places where a keypath can be provided. For example, you can easily get dates from (or since) a specific year using `NSPredicate`.